# Python recursively mock entire module for unittesting

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test a class, let's call it A. As part of A's instantiation, it tries to create instances of many classes from a package external.

```
from external import B, C, D

class A
    def __init__(self, some_config):
        b_config, c_config, d_config = self._generate_config(some_config)
        b = B(b_config)
        c = C(c_config)
        d = D(d_config)
```

I don't want to instantiate anything from external for my unit test, but the nature of the codebase is that I also don't want to pass b, c, or d in as external arguments for the constructor.

I know using mock.patch, I can write a test

```
@mock.patch(external.D, autospec=True)
@mock.patch(external.C, autospec=True)
@mock.patch(external.B, autospec=True)
def test(self, b_patch: mock.MagicMock,
               c_patch: mock.MagicMock,
               d_patch: mock.MagicMock):
    b_patch.return_value = mock.Mock()
    c_patch.return_value = mock.Mock()
    d_patch.return_value = mock.Mock()

    test_a = A()
    # Assert no problems with instantiating A
    # AKA self._generate_config worked
```

But is there an easy way to mark all classes inside `external` such that they should be mocked like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code isn't self-consistent -- in your first example you're doing `from external import B` and in the second example it looks like you did `import external`.  In the second form you're able to just patch `external`:

```
import external

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        b = external.B()
        c = external.C()
        d = external.D()

from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('__main__.external')
def test(mock_external):
    test_a = A()

test()
```

The above test passes regardless of the contents of `external.py` (as long as it doesn't raise an error on the initial import) because the test patches out the entire module.

It's not necessary to individually assign all the different attributes of `external` to `Mock` objects because every attribute of a `Mock` is already an auto-created `Mock` unless you set it to something else.

If there is no `external` name in the module under test (because you did `from external import B` etc) you need to individually patch the `B`, `C`, and `D` names.